# rpm package info leak?

Tags: linux, data-leakage

On Linux, `rpm -qi <package-name>` command would display the package info, which would contain information of build machine - `Build Host :<host-name>`

Does this pose any security risk? Is this information classified as sensitive?
I believe svn repositories and build environment details should not be disclosed in customer environment. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you wouldn't expose build data. However, in order to run commands such as `rpm -qi` you would need to have a shell account on the server. This implies a certain level of trust for your user.

It would be possible to restrict the use of the `rpm` command to administrators (assuming it is not already the case), which implies an even higher level of trust. In this case, it doesn't matter - they could just as easily replace your software, install other packages, or take over the box. Essentially, at this point, being able to see the information isn't an issue.

If you have a box set up which *anyone* can run this sort of command, yes, it's an issue, but this isn't generally the case.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow what you are saying Matthew. I think that the concern is that the host information is disclosing information about the environment that was used for the build. I don't see how that interacts with needing to have a shell account on the client running `rpm`.

Comment: Why would that be a security risk? For the most part, this would be a box controlled by the distribution. It's not a box under the end user's control